# Making a player object move using OOP C#

Tags: c#, oop, console-application

I need some help. I have been stuck with this one forever and I need some help. So we are supposed to create a game which uses OOP principals. The game grid is created with a 2D array that we create in an abstract class called Map.cs. But I'm stuck trying to figure out how to make the player object ('@') being print out on the map, whilst in the class Player.cs
I can only show you this code from the Map.cs because the player class is a mess

Map.cs

```
    abstract class Map
{
    public const int RAD = 10;
    public const int KOLUMN = 19;

    public string[,] table = new string[RAD, KOLUMN];
    public Map()
    {
        //Creates the map
        for (int i = 0; i < RAD; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < KOLUMN; j++)
            {
                table[i, j] = ".";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is Map abstract? You do know that an abstract class can't be instantiated, right?

Comment: @ZoharPeled oh okey, didn't know that, thank you

Comment: Map should not be abstract, by the way.

printing the map should be in another class. Say you have these three classes
- Map
- Player
- Engine (for example). Engine should have variables `private Map map` and `private Player player`, and a method `void PrintMap()`. Foreach element of the 2D array in the map, you will check if the x and y coordinates equal the position of the player - if yes, you will print '@' instead of the element in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Using your Map class (I have renamed the constants to ROWS and COLUMNS), I have written the following sample class for the player.

```
public class Player
{
    public int PositionX { get; set; }
    public int PositionY { get; set; }
    // constructors
}
```

Then in the main class you can have the following. Note, this will be printing the (0,0) at the top left corner and will maybe mess up columns and rows, but you should be able to make it work after you understand this *very basic* idea.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Map map = new Map();
    Player player = new Player();
    PrintMap(map, player);
}

static void PrintMap(Map map, Player player)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Map.ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Map.COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            if (player.PositionX == i && player.PositionY == j)
            {
                Console.Write('@');
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(map.table[i, j]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

One thing to remember is, in OOP programming (and following the SOLID design principles) each class should be responsible for only one thing. Holding the map state and printing the map are two completely different tasks : it's better to create a map class that saves the state and implement the printing elsewhere.